# How to iterate over `dict` in class like if just referring to `dict`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

In a defined object some values are kept in a `dict`, and I want to iterate over the contents in that `dict` as when referring to a plain `dict`, thus with directly access using `[]`, and loop using e.g. `.items()`.  Code structure is:

```
class Klass:

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values
        self.more = None

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.values[name]

    def __iter__(self):
        pass  # TBD[How to make this ?]

d = {'alfa': 1, 'bravo': 2, 'charlie': 3}

k = Klass(d)

for key in k:
    print(key)  # Expected to print keys from self.values 

for (key, value) in k.items():
    print(key, value)  # Expected to print key and value from self.values 

for key in k.keys():
    print(key)  # Expected to print key from self.values 

for value in k.values():
    print(value)  # Expected to print value from self.values
```

How to write the `__iter__` and, other required methods, so this kind of access is possible through an instance of Klass?

Comment: `for item in self.values: yield item`?

Comment: The intention with OOP is to hide specific implementation, so direct reference to instance attribute `.values` should be avoided..

Comment: @EquipDev: **within the implementation** you are still going to have to rely on your own state. `Torxed` was proposing a implementation for `__iter__`, making it a generator function. Not needed here, not with `iter()`, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Now I see; yes that adheres to OOP principles.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to implement the `.keys()`, `.values()` and `.items()` methods yourself; together with `__iter__` they can all delegate the actual work to the `self.values()` dictionary:

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self._values = values
        self.more = None

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._values[name]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._values)

    def keys(self):
        return self._values.keys()

    def items(self):
        return self._values.items()

    def values(self):
        return self._values.values()
```

I renamed the attribute to avoid masking the `.values()` method.

The easiest way to delegate `__iter__` to iteration over the dictionary (by key) is to use the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to get an iterator for the dictionary object.

To be explicit: `__iter__` plays no role in how `.keys()`, `.values()` and `.items()` are handled; the latter are *just more methods*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for renaming `values` to `_values`; it was a bad choice of name when having to implement the `values` method.

Comment: There's no need to implement `.keys()` etc.  Just subclass from `collections.abc.Mapping`.

Comment: @Kevin: yup, that's the next step. The fact that `collections.abc.Mapping` then implements those methods doesn't diminishes the fact that those methods need to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

```py
    class Klass(dict):
        def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
            super(Klass, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)
            self.choosebettername = super(Klass, self).keys()

        def __iter__(self):
            return iter(self.choosebettername)

        def keys(self):
            return self.choosebettername

        def itervalues(self):
            return (self[key] for key in self)


    d = {'alfa': 1, 'bravo': 2, 'charlie': 3}

    k = Klass(d)

    for key in k:
        print(key)  # Expected to print keys from self.values 

    for (key, value) in k.items():
        print(key, value)  # Expected to print key and value from self.values 

    for key in k.keys():
        print(key)  # Expected to print key from self.values 

    print(k.values())

    for value in k.values():
        print(value)  # Expected to print value from self.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) behavior, one might simply let the default iteration method be the [items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)' dictionary view:

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self._values = values

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._values[name]

    def __iter__(self):
        iter(self._values.items())


klass = Klass({'alfa': 1, 'bravo': 2, 'charlie': 3})

for key, value in klass:
    print(key, value)
```